# Configure port of spring-boot application for deployment in weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I want to deploy an application on a weblogic server with the port configured. Currently already deploy correctly with the defined context-path, but the value that I have defined in the port does not work.

My weblogic version is 12c, and the actual configuration is (application.properties):

```
    server.port = 8585
```

I hope that the port is the one configured previously, but there is deployed in the port of the server, 7001

EDIT:

For reference, I followed this tutorial to make the deployment in weblogic: https://o7planning.org/en/11901/deploying-spring-boot-application-on-oracle-weblogic-server

Surely it is not a good idea to use spring boot to deploy it in weblogic but it is a project that I did not start and I must develop and maintain.

All I need is to be able to change the port

Comment: I have no idea what your question is...

Comment: Sounds confusing, can you elaborate your question? btw: I had the chance to work with weblogic .. A ready-to-go spring-boot app deployed there is such a waste of resources.